# While statement, not taking same image in animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, while-loop

i need some help with making a `while statement`. I got different images in my animation.
But i don't want to display same image after the animation.

Ex. how it works now: image1 shows -> image3 shows -> image3 shows.

i want it to always be a new image showing.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];


int interval = 5+(arc4random() % 6);

int section = 0;
int row = (arc4random() % self.jsonDict.count);


NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateCells:)
                               userInfo:indexPath
                                repeats:NO];

    NSLog(@"seconds: %d", interval);
    NSLog(@"row: %d", row);}



- (void)updateCells:(NSTimer *)timer {



NSIndexPath *indexPath = [timer userInfo];
NSObject *obj = [_jsonDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"array: %@", obj);

UIImage *img = [self randomImageWithObject:obj];

NSString *title = [obj valueForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(@"array: %@", title);

CollectionCell *cell = (CollectionCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[UIView transitionWithView:cell
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                   cell.collectionImageView.image = img;
                } completion:nil];



int interval = 5+(arc4random() % 6);
int section = 0;
int row = (arc4random() % [_jsonDict count]);

NSLog(@"speedeee: %d", interval);
NSLog(@"row: %d", row);

NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];



//CollectionCell *newCell = (CollectionCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateCells:)
                               userInfo:indexPath2
                                repeats:NO];}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [_jsonDict count];}-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSObject *obj = [_jsonDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//NSLog(@"object: %@", obj);

NSArray *images = [obj valueForKey:@"images"];
NSString *imageName = images[0];
//NSLog(@"name: %@", imageName);

cell.collectionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];


[self cellTitleAndBackground:cell indexPath:indexPath];

return cell;}

- (UIImage *)randomImageWithObject:(NSObject *)obj{
// Random image for cells



NSArray *images = [obj valueForKey:@"images"];
NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % [images count];

return [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:randomNumber]];}
```

Comment: The use of a `while` statement is almost certainly wrong as it sounds like you'll be blocking the UI thread.  You need to use completion blocks or somesuch and keep state so you know what action you want to initiate next.

Comment: Pasting some sample code you are working with will be huge help

Comment: Added some of my code to show you. @GrzegorzKrukowski

Answer (score 1):

I Thing you want continues animation then no need to creating while loop in ios

In UIImageView have some properties , You can use like this

```
UIImageView *imageView ;
NSArray *imagesArray ;
[imageView setAnimationImages:imagesArray];
[imageView setAnimationDuration:time];
[imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:count];
```

Answer (score 0):

For collection you should use:

```
indexPath.item
```

instead of

```
indexPath.row
```

Read more here (row for TableView, item for CollectionView):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html